# Is there a way to limit the amount of times a unique value is returned in a table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

As a preface, it seems as though our server runs 5.5.56-MariaDB.

For examples sake, I'm currently in a position where I can return data like below:

**Data _|_Quantity**
00001  |  1000
00001  |  900
00001  |  800
00001  |  700
00002  |  600
00002  |  500
00002  |  400
00003  |  300
00003  |  200
00003  |  100

The Data and Quantity values are pulled fairly easily using Groups and Counts and Joins from other tables. However, I'm trying to only return the two highest quantity values from each piece of data pulled - so in effect, I want the outcome to be more like this:

**Data _|_Quantity**
00001  |  1000
00001  |  900
00002  |  600
00002  |  500
00003  |  300
00003  |  200

The values have not changed, I just am not returning the data which isn't relevant to me. 
I've been fiddling with nesting tables and counts and groups and anything else I can think of, but the closest I've came is returning only the highest value, which doesn't suit my needs.

I am well and truly stumped on how to continue here, and I can't seem to be able to find any other people who have needed a similar return on their data, so if anyone can provide any guidance, I would greatly appreciate it.

Many thanks.

Comment: See the tag I added.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` can be used here:

```
SELECT Data, Quantity
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Data ORDER BY Quantity DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE
    rn <= 2
ORDER BY
    Data,
    Quantity DESC;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, it is possible to simulate the row number using user variables, but it takes more code.  If you have a long term need for such queries, consider upgrading.

Comment: An elegant solution but it seems as though you're right in saying that I'm on an older version. Thank you for trying, though.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structured_Query_Language/Retrieve_Top_N_Rows_per_Group has a couple of examples of how you can do this.

In one of the use-cases I had a long time back I used a query of the form below

```
 SELECT *
FROM   table_temp
WHERE  quantity = (SELECT Max(quantity)
                   FROM   table_temp AS t
                   WHERE  t.data = table_temp.data)
        OR quantity = (SELECT Max(quantity)
                       FROM   table_temp AS t
                       WHERE  t.data = table_temp.data
                              AND quantity < (SELECT Max(quantity)
                                              FROM   table_temp AS t2
                                              WHERE  t2.data = table_temp.data))
```

This picks the top quantity of a group and the next value to it has well.

The first filter on quality pull the max in a group, the second filter pulls the second largest quantity.

Solution by  Tim Biegeleisen, however, is more elegant given that it can be extended to any number of values without much complexity in the SQL.

SQL Fiddle for the same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/372454/8

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a query, you could try something like this

```
SELECT
    T.Data,
    T.Quantity
From
(
    SELECT 
        Data,
        Quantity,
        if(@id = TT0.data, (select(@i := @i + 1)), (select(@i := 0))) as R, -- if previous id == data then row +1 else r=0
        @id := TT0.data -- assign Data to @id variable
    FROM
        YourTable as T0, (select @i:= 0, @id := null ) as Rows -- cross join initialise @i and @id
) AS T
WHERE
    T.R < 2; -- row numbers you are interested in
```

for limitations and more info : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html